# JavaScript: Adding to an associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I have a function called insert which takes two parameters (*name* and *telnumber*).

When I call this function I want to add to an associative array.

So for example, when I do the following:

```
insert("John", "999");
insert("Adam", "5433");
```

I want to it so be stored like this:

```
[0]
{
name: John, number: 999
}
[1]
{
name: Adam, number: 5433
}
```

Comment: "associative arrays" are just objects in JavaScript.

Comment: Technically, you mean you want to add objects to an array which is numerically indexed. JavaScript doesn't have "associative" arrays.

Comment: Please show your existing function definition, and how you have defined the array it adds to

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var arr = [];
function insert(name, number) {
    arr.push({
        name: name,
        number: number
    });        
}
```

Comment: You might point out that OP is *not* using an associative array; he's using an array of objects.

Answer (score 5):

I would use something like this;

```
var contacts = [];
var addContact = function(name, phone) {
    contacts.push({ name: name, phone: phone });
};

// Usage
addContact('John', '999');
addContact('Adam', '5433');
```

I don’t think you should try to parse the phone number as an integer as it could contain white-spaces, plus signs (+) and maybe even start with a zero (0).

Comment: Good point about the parseInt, I just saw "Number"- didn't think about the context :-)

Comment: Just spotted, the `contacts` var above should be `[]` not `{}`.

Answer (score 4):

```
var users = [];

users.push({name: "John", number: "999"});
users.push({name: "Adam", number: "5433"});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want you can add your function to `Array.prototype`.

```
Array.prototype.insert = function( key, val ) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[ key ] = val;
    this.push( obj );
    return this;
};
```

And use it like this.

```
var my_array = [].insert("John", "999")
                 .insert("Adam", "5433")
                 .insert("yowza", "1");

[
   0: {"John":"999"},
   1: {"Adam":"5433"},
   2: {"yowza":"1"}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you're using some array reference with `insert`:

```
var arr;
function insert(na, nu) {
  nu = Number(nu) || 0;
  //alternatively
  nu = parseInt(nu, 10);
  arr.push({ name: na, number: nu });
}
arr = [];


insert("John", "999");
insert("Adam", "5433");
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no such term as an "associative array" in JavaScript, though you can use following:

```
var list = [];

function insert(name, number) {
  list.push({
    name: name,
    number: number
  });
}
```

Comment: eh? here's [another one from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/5kh4af6c(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: "objects as associative arrays" doesn't mean that JS has "associative arrays". everything is an object in JS and you can add properties to anything but it doesn't make these objects associative arrays.

btw who downvoted my answer? :)))))))))) it's funny :D

Comment: Technically any turning complete language can implement anything any other turing complete language. Thus all computer languages have associative arrays (minus ones like SQL). Also in JS, objects are implemented using lists of name/attribute pairs --  this is possible in JS and not other OO languages like Java since JS treats functions as first class citizens, so in fact they are "associative arrays as objects" not the other way around. and javascript does have them.

Comment: love all these comments... do you guys write these comments with serious faces? :)))) thumbs up to down voters. did you try to find "associative array" definition in EcmaScript document?

Comment: The problem is that assciative array is not a 'thing' it is a particular behavior of an array. Javascript has arrays that can be addresses associativly. How javascript choses to implement that or what it chosew to call it is javascript's choice but java script still has it. Saying javascript doesnt have associative arrays is like saying perl doesnt have functions because it uses 'subroutines'.